# move_uploaded_file not working in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I am trying to move uploaded picture into destination but the `move_uploaded_file(` funtion not working for me. I'm using xampp as my server. I tried some suggestions but nothing is working

```
$file = $_FILE['image']['tmp_name'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$imgName = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$imgSize = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$des = "C:\xampp\htdocs\proPic";
move_uploaded_file($file,$des.$imgName);
//mysql query
```

Comment: Why are you `addslashes` to a file_get_content() That is potentially messing with the content of your image file. == Instant destruction of the image

Comment: As 2 people can quite easily upload a file called `mypic.jpg` it is better to create a local unique filename for these uploaded images

Comment: ___funtion not working for me___ Not very helpful. In what way is it not working. Does file not get saved? Is file damaged and unreadable? Please be specific about what ___not working___ means

Comment: move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$des.$imgName); Try this one

Comment: i m using addslashes for security reasons.and  i tried to remove it and still doesnt work.my file doesnt move to the folder.but it succesfully inserts into database.

Comment: move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$des.$imgNa‌​me);tried this one but still image does not get into the folder

Comment: Backslashes are great for everything. When my plants are infested with aphids I just drop some backslashes and they get much better. And you should see what backslashes can do for your car's engine in cold winters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I changed two things

1.Add the missing **S** in $file variable, Like this  $file = $_FILE**S**['image']['tmp_name'];

2.Change destination path variable($dec), Like this **$des = "C:/xampp/htdocs/proPic";**

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$imgName = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$imgSize = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$des = "C:/xampp/htdocs/proPic";
move_uploaded_file($file,$des.$imgName);
```

Comment: thank u very much for your support but i tried everything.nothing is working.still i can succesfully insert image as blob into database but picture not moving inside folder.maybe somthing can i do in php.ini file?i also changed the max_upload_size still no use.

Comment: if u r using linux operating system means give 777 permission in upload folder. Its working fine in localhost..

Answer (score 0):

Form what I see on your code you are missing `\` on your `$des`.

Try adding `\` at the end

```
$des = "C:\xampp\htdocs\proPic\";
```

Because `addslashes` only returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`), backslash (`\`) and `NUL` (the NULL byte). See [here for docs on `addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: if i add a \ at last before " it somehow disables the rest of the code.

Comment: can you echo out and check `echo $des.$imgName` if you are missing `\` then that's the problem with code,